# Getting error : 'Example' object has no attribute 'grid_1'

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to link wxpython gui with sqlite database. .I have made a table in my database(RAMAN.db). My GUI is basically a grid and i want to add buttons in that,so the GUI should take input directly from database. I want to print name on each button from the database table. In the table i have given row and column number which correspond to row and column number of grid. My database Table is: https://pastebin.com/PXLfCrNW I don't understand exactly how to do that I have tried this `

```
import wx
import sqlite3
import wx.grid
import os

cwd = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

def connect(): #this is the sqlite3 connection
conn = sqlite3.connect('RAMAN.db')
return conn
conn.close()

def data_rows_count(): #to count the rows in the database
conn = connect()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM ELEMENT")
rows = cur.fetchall()
i = 0
for r in rows:
  i += 1
return i

class Example(wx.Frame):

  def __init__(self, parent, title):
  super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (800, 600))

self.InitUI()
self.Layout()
self.Centre()
self.Show()

def refresh_data(self):
  conn = connect()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Phone")
rows = cur.fetchall()
for i in range(0, len(rows)):
  for j in range(0, 4):
  cell = rows[i]
self.grid_1.SetCellValue(i, j, str(cell[j]))


def InitUI(self):
  self.grid_1 = wx.grid.Grid(self, -1, size = (1, 1))
p = wx.Panel(self)
r = data_rows_count()
self.grid_1.CreateGrid(r, 1)# this is to create the grid with same rows as database
self.grid_1.SetColLabelValue(0, ("SYMBOL"))
self.grid_1.SetColSize(0, 12)
bs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
self.t1 = wx.TextCtrl(p, size = (120, 30), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_CENTER)
bs.Add(self.t1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
bs.Add(grid_1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
self.refresh_data()

def clk_h(self, event):
  r = data_rows_count
for e in range(0, r):
  for f in range(0, 103):
  self.grid_1.SetCellValue(e, f, "")
conn = connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
currsor.execute("SELECT SYMBOL FROM ELEMENT")
conn.commit()
rows = cursor.fetchall()
btn = wx.Button(p, -1, h, (10, 20))
btn.myname = h
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn)
grid_1.Add(btn, 0, wx.EXPAND)
for i in range(len(rows)):
  for j in range(0, 4):
  cell = rows[i]
self.grid_1.SetCellValue(i, j, str(cell[j]))
conn.close()
event.Skip()

p.SetSizer(bs)

def OnClick(self, event):
  name = event.GetEventObject().myname
self.t1.AppendText(name)
self.t1.AppendText("\n")


app = wx.App()
Example(None, title = 'Grid demo')

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This means your class `Example` doesn't have `grid_1` when your code is trying to access it. Can you copy-paste the error as it is, with line number?

Comment: line87, line 28 and line 54 Error: global name 'grid 1' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You are using `grid_1` as opposed to `self.grid_1`
here:

```
bs.Add(grid_1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

and here:

```
grid_1.Add(btn, 0, wx.EXPAND)
```

Comment: Still I am getting that error and i want to link the database with my GUI. I dont understand exactly how to do that. Can you please help me out?         https://github.com/svnitHIMANSHU/Raman-spectroscopy-database

Comment: @HimanshuPareek In a word, No! As far as I can tell, you have asked 9 questions concerning the same code. So far you have not accepted a single one of the 8 answers that were posted. I believe that I have prodded you towards reading the StackOverflow tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour 3 times and yet for whatever reason you have not bothered or you thought that the points there did not apply to you. Every answer provided here on SO, has been provided after time, effort and thought have been put into them. As you show no sign of appreciation of that, I will be helping others, Good luck!

Comment: I am really sorry. Actually I have to finish this very soon. So I was confused and I am very new to this.  I apologize for that. Next time I won't do this mistake. Please ?